# Help me out to understand the Text.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

I can't understand the bijection. I am new to this. I have underlined my doubts, please help me.

Comment: May, I know the reason dear downvoter ? So I can keep it in my mind for next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great example of where you have to understand *everything* about a function -- not just the "rule", but the domain and codomain as well. The "rule" is, as Shaun observed, "drop the last item". But the domain is $X_n$, the sequences in $S_n$ *that end with a one*. So the author could have equally well written the rule as

$$
(x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1}, 1) \mapsto (x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1})
$$
In THIS form, it's pretty clearly injective: if you have two sequences on the left that go to the same sequence on the right, they're clearly equal. (Both are just the right-hand sequence with a "1" appended!)

The next question is whether the function is *surjective*, i.e., given a sequence in $S_{n-1}$, say $(u_1, \ldots, u_{k-1})$, is there a sequence in $X_n$ that is mapped to it? Answer: sure. Use the sequence

$$
(u_1, \ldots, u_{k-1}, 1)
$$
So it's both injective and surjective, hence bijective. But if you take the domain to be "all sequences" rather than "sequences that sum to $n$ and terminate with a 1", then it's *not* bijective. Domains and codomains matter.

Comment: What is a right hand sequence ?

Comment: The sequence of numbers on the right-hand side of the equals-sign.

Answer (score 1):

Given the sequence $(x_1,\dots, x_k)$, it deletes the last (rightmost) entry, yielding $(x_1,\dots, x_{k-1})$; for example, if $k=3$, then $(1,2,1)\mapsto (1,2)$.

Comment: But how is this fuction bijective and is that mapping valid ?

Comment: It isn't a bijection, @NikolaAlfredi. It has no well-defined inverse. To see this, note that $(1,2,3)\mapsto (1,2)$ but also $(1,2,4)\mapsto (1,2)$.

Comment: Ok, then what does that function mean ?

Comment: And why is the correspondence valid

Comment: It means precisely what it says: it deletes the last entry, @NikolaAlfredi.

Comment: Wait a minute, here we can only use 1 and 2 , would that alter the result ?

Comment: Define "valid," @NikolaAlfredi.

Comment: What result, @NikolaAlfredi?

Comment: Valid : We are mapping elements of $X_n$ to some elements of $X_{n-1}$. I am doubtful in this. Please tell what is  mapping here , I believe that my meaning of valid is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$X_k$ is always $1$, so given the first $k - 1$ elements of a sequence $(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k) \in X_n$, you can uniquely determine the original sequence by appending an $1$.  Moreover, the sequence $(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_{k-1})$ is a sequence in $S_{n-1}$ because its elements sum to $n - 1$. Therefore, the mapping is bijection from $X_k$ to $S_{n-1}$.